# How to mock method of Injected service in Spring Integration Tests

Tags: spring, mockito

I have following service class, that I want to test

```
@Service
public class MasterService {

    @Inject
    private ServiceOne serviceOne;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;

    @Inject
    private ServiceThree serviceThree;

    @VisibleForTesting
    void execute() {
        if (serviceThree.isFlag()) {
           ....
        }
    }
```

I am testing `execute()` method. **I want to mock `serviceThree.isFlag()` to return true.** Following is my test.

```
    public class MasterServiceIT{

        @Inject
        private MasterService masterService;

        @Inject
        private ServiceThree serviceThree;

        @Test
        public void testMasterService() {
            when(serviceThree.isFlag()).thenReturn(true); <---- this never works 
            masterService.execute();
        }
    }
```

However, it never retrieves true. Any remarks? I wanted to use `@InjectMocks` Then can I inject only this service which I mocked? or I need to mock each service if I am using `@InjectMocks`

Comment: My concern is to when I put debug on, I reach to the implementation of executeJob() and this line  if (!ruleSwitchService.isJobReexecutionEnabled()) never resolve to true. Which I want to mock

Comment: I edited my question.If you could help now

Comment: The problem is that your you inject the two object and try to alter a method on injected object. Mockito cannot alter real object's methods. You must create a mock to alter, or spy to inject dependencies, and use `@InjectMocks` on under test object. Do not forget to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or initialize with `Mockito.initMocks(this)`

Comment: If you are using mock, then it's not anymore an integration test. So firstly, you should remove the IT part from  MasterServiceIT class, just from naming convention point of view. Secondly, as @zlaval mentioned, you need to put those annotations, plus Mock annotation on serviceThree property. Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks to @SebastianC. to point it. If you want to create an integration test, you have to setup the container and use real objects without mockito, there you shoudnt use any mock.
If that was your purpose, you can easily done the container setup with `@SpringBootTest` annotation. 
But from the context of the question, I guess you want to create an unit test.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you need to mock for an integration test? Well, sometimes there are cases when we need to mock some service which refers to some external services like SharePoint, etc. Well if you need to mock so in this case you need to mock spring service bean in spring context. You can do it via `@MockBean`